# Tech Tree layouts for games?

Tags: gui, graphics-design, user-experience

I'm trying to do a tech tree GUI for my game, but i have limited width and the tree has alot of branches, the problem is if I make them small to fit the width, the tech tree is too small to read.

For example the AOE one is very large (in width):
[image]

I could allow scroll bar but as its web based, scrolls are quite ugly. So i was wondering how to deal with branches which slowly cause the tech tree to get wider as you go down the tech tree and how you would fit such a design in a limited space.

Are there different known designs for tech trees that any one knows of so i can look at their types. I don't know the names given to the types of tech tree layouts. But am hoping to find one that is not overly complex for the user aswell.

Comment: I played a lot of games with complex tech trees, but I can't remember just one which had a GUI for them which was halfway decent.

Comment: Mousewheel doesnot scroll, but zoom in / out. Clickmove pans.

Comment: @Philipp i agree theres very few that are decent.

Comment: Maybe how it is done in the game World of Tanks? http://i.solidfiles.net/277920b7b8.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an indented tech tree, assuming you don't have too many layers.  It is probably easier to show what I mean than it is to explain it.  An excerpt from an example AoE2 tech tree below:

- **Barracks (I)**

  - Militia (I)

    - Man-at-Arms (II)

      - Long Swordsman (III)

        - Two-Handed Swordsman (IV)

          - Champion (IV)
  - Spearman (II)

    - Pikeman (III)

      - Halberdier (IV)
  - Eagle Warrior (III)

    - Elite Eagle Warrior (IV)
  - *Tracking (II)*
  - *Squires (III)*
  - **Archery Range (II)**

    - Archer (II)

      - Crossbowman (III)

        - Arbalest (IV)
    - Skirmisher (II)

      - Elite Skirmisher (III)
    - Cavalry Archer (III)

      - Heavy Cav Archer (IV)
    - Hand Cannoneer (IV)
    - *Thumb Ring (III)*
    - *Parthian Tactics (IV)*
  - **Stable (II)**

    - Scout Cavalry (II)

      - Light Cavalry (III)

        - Hussar (IV)
    - Knight (III)

      - Cavalier (IV)

        - Paladin (IV)
    - Camel (III)

      - Heavy Camel (IV)
    - *Bloodlines (II)*
    - *Husbandry (III)*
- **Mining Camp (I)**

  - *Gold Mining (II)*

    - *Gold Shaft Mining (III)*
  - *Stone Mining (II)*

    - *Stone Shaft Mining (III)*
- **Lumber Camp (I)**

  - *Double-Bit Axe (II)*

    - *Bow Saw (III)*

      - *Two-Man Saw (IV)*

Of course, if you can code the tree so that it is possible to expand the list (eg have the technologies within the Mining Camp hidden unless expanded), and display detailed information (such as cost, time, etc. on mouse hover), you would be able to put even more information into a small space.  The only problem with this design is that it still needs a scroll bar, but I have seen some working scroll bars online.  Be aware that my knowledge of web coding is rather limited though, so I am afraid I can't help much on implementation.
I hope that helps.
Mmarss

Comment: This doesn't really help out that much as the OP was looking for ways of representing graphical branching information whereas your example is very linear. If anything it basically converts it from a horizontal representation into a vertical one which doesn't help reduce the complexity of the graph.

Comment: It would be possible to represent the above graphically, with vertical lines connecting each bullet point to the directly subordinate ones, but I would have to agree that it is still complicated.  However, to my mind at least, the linear nature of the above example makes a lot of sense, and (to me, at least) is very clear.  I also believe that the OP was looking for a way of representing a lot of horizontal information in a narrow space, which my example does.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, a list like that is much more readable than a actual tree.

Comment: Also vertical scrolling is much more comfortable than horizontal scrolling.

Comment: What if a single research project allowed 2 different path choices, where by its an "either/or" situation ?

Comment: In that case, unfortunately, it would need to be specified with a separate comment.  Of course, while it would add more dynamics to the game, not many games (at least RTS games that I play) have multiple paths in an exclusive or setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more then one picture ie. your agro advancements can be on one graph
wile your writing advancements can be on another and when it gets to confusing to put on 1 graph split them up again